# Macro Issue After Upgrade kentico V11 --> V12

Tags: macros, kentico

I've a question about the upgrade of Kentico V11 --> V12.
After the correct migration, I got these errors messages (20 times).

When I'll check the website, all design are blank. I just have the menu link without design.
I already re-sign the macro.
I've check all version of CMS.*.dll --> V12.

Do you have any idea for this blocking issue ?

Kind regards !

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSkkU.png)

Comment: Welcome. Can you copy the text of the error message itself into your question? That will make it easier for the community to review—and, hopefully, answer your question. It will also help people find this question in the future, if they run into similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just give you a feedback.
The problem seems to be during the migration...

Due to the VPN low speed, that possible there was some timeout for many steps. (mandatory because the COVID19 =( )

I just get the database on my local computer and redone the migration, and all seems to be good now.

Thank you for your help on this subject :)

Take care of you in this period !

Answer (score 0):

did you [resign all the macros](https://docs.kentico.com/k12sp/macro-expressions/troubleshooting-macros/working-with-macro-signatures#Workingwithmacrosignatures-Re-signingmacros) after the upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Typically there are a few things which can cause this.  First being the hash salt changed in the web.config.  If this changed, you need to resign your macros.  Even if your hash salt hasn't changed the easiest thing is to go to System > Macros and check both boxes and resign all the macros.

The second thing, highly unlikely, would be you need to clear your browsers cache. Sometimes JS errors arise from the upgrade and cause problems with the system not running code.

Comment: Hi Brenden,
Thank you for your reply !
I tried these points :
1) Update Macro signatures --> System > Macros > Signatures
2) Clear cache  --> System > Clear cache + restart application

But always the same problem...
When I check the Event logs, I see 25 MacroResolver issue

 MacroResolver RESOLVEDATAMACRO
msg : ...  CMS.MacroEngine.EvaluationException: Exception occurred while evaluation of the expression '... Method 'GetFileUrlFromAlias' for object of type 'System.Guid' not found, please check the macro or the method declaration....

Comment: @jayrko is the method `GetFileUrlFromAlias()` a custom macro method?  If so you may want to re-evaluate that custom code and make sure it has the proper parameters and output values.

Answer (score 0):

What is the entire error message? What is the source URL and where is the code which is throwing the error? Isn't it possible it is coming from some transformation? I am asking since there were some API changes and the GetFileUrlFromAlias method was removed. See the [API changes](https://devnet.kentico.com/documentation/api-changes/kentico-12/26043). You may want to use the [Code upgrade tool](https://docs.kentico.com/k12sp/installation/upgrading-to-kentico-12/upgrading-custom-code) to detect such changes.

Comment: Hi Jurajo,

The code is good because, we already tried in the past to make an update V11 -> V12 and my code is working with this database.
For now, we want to make a new update for another database V11 -> V12 but my code doesn't work with this database. So I think that the problem come from the migration and not from my code.